# Setting range properly in DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet (VBA Access in Excel)?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, backup, data-transfer

```
For Each Page In Worksheets
    PageName = Split(Page.Name, " ")
    If UBound(PageName) > 0 Then
        Worksheets(Page.Name).Activate
        lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Fullrange = Worksheets(Page.Name).Range(Worksheets(Page.Name).Cells(1, 1), _
            Worksheets(Page.Name).Cells(lRow, LCol))
        accappl.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            Page.Name, strpathxls, True, Fullrange
    End If
Next
```

I have written this code in VBA Excel to backup data into access from excel. The code doesn't like the way that I wrote the range in my for each loops. I also tried the 2nd for each loop, but that just backed up the main page repeatedly( with the correct table names though).

I think the 1st way is close, but I don't understand what is wrong with FullRange line which is type Range.

EDIT: The error is object variable or with block variable not set on the FullRange line

Update 6-18, It seems that the fullrange should be in the form string. I have edited a little but the error I am getting now on the transferspreadsheet line is "The Microsoft database engine could not find the object'1301 Array$A$1:J$12'. Make sure that the object exists and you spell its name correctly.

I took out fullrange and put in page.name and it gave me the same error.

```
For Each Page In Worksheets
    PageName = Split(Page.Name, " ")
    If UBound(PageName) > 0 Then
        ' Worksheets(Page.Name).Activate - this line is most likely not needed
        lRow = Page.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = Page.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        fullRange = Page.Name & Page.Range(Page.Cells(1, 1), _
            Page.Cells(lRow, LCol)).Address
        accappl.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, Page.Name, strpathxls, True, Page.Name
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit, have a look see if you can see where youve gone wrong.

```
Dim Page As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, LCol As Long
Dim fullRange As Range
Dim PageName As Variant

For Each Page In Worksheets

    PageName = Split(Page.Name, " ")

    If UBound(PageName) > 0 Then
        ' Worksheets(Page.Name).Activate - this line is most likely not needed
        lRow = Page.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = Page.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set fullRange = Page.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, LCol))
        accappl.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, Page.Name, strpathxls, True, fullRange
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I commented out the fullrange under the dim pagename as variant, since I need that to update. Fullrange in the for each loop gave me the range method failed errror. I made some changes, and now have the same error as before.

Comment: hm... try with the `Set fullRange`

Comment: I put a small update. Turns out full range has to be a string, but since I need a the entire sheet anyway I replace the range in accppl.docmd line as page name, gives Update 6-18, It seems that the fullrange should be in the form string. I have edited a little but the error I am getting now on the transferspreadsheet line is "The Microsoft database engine could not find the object'1301 Array$A$1:J$12'. Make sure that the object exists and you spell its name correctly.

Comment: `Range("A1:A50").Address` returns a String representation of the range

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code, the range has to have a ! in it for some reason.

```
  Sub BU_ACCESS()

Dim accappl As Access.Application
Dim strpathdb As String
Dim strpathxls As String
'Dim myrange As String, myrow1 As String, myrow2 As String
'Dim fullRange As Range



strpathdb = "C:\Users\tgfesaha\Desktop\Database1.accdb"
'path to the upload file

strpathxls = ActiveWorkbook.FullName




Set accappl = New Access.Application

accappl.OpenCurrentDatabase strpathdb
Dim Page As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, LCol As Long
Dim fullrange As String
Dim PageName As Variant
'fullRange = Worksheets(Page.Name).Range(Worksheets(Page.Name).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(Page.Name).Cells(lRow, LCol))

For Each Page In Worksheets

    PageName = Split(Page.Name, " ")

    If UBound(PageName) > 0 Then
        ' Worksheets(Page.Name).Activate - this line is most likely not needed
        lRow = Page.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = Page.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        fullrange = Page.Range(Page.Cells(1, 1), Page.Cells(lRow, LCol)).Address
        xclam = Page.Name & "!" & fullranges

        accappl.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, Page.Name, strpathxls, True, xclam
    End If
Next

accappl.Quit

End Sub
```